# Does height of load on forklift affect its balance?

Tags: gravity

Let's say I put load on the forklift and lift it to 50cm. Will the balance change with lifting it higher? Meaning, will it ever tip over? Assuming there is no other movement "inside" the forklift.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As you lift the forklift, the center of mass of the system will go up. For the forklift to remain balanced, the COM must remain over the base of the forklift. If the COM moves off the base of the forklift, you will have a net torque which will move to topple the forklift. The higher the COM is, the easier it is to make it move away from the base of the forklift.

Comment: Your description here is incomplete. The CoM goes *up* which does not move it out of the support polygon (or more often up and slightly back, which is even better). However, there is an issue with having a raised load: when starting, stopping or turning the effective direction of gravity is changed, and *then* having a high CoM is trouble because the projected location for non-vertical effective gravity can fall outside the support polygon. Lesson: move slowly when you have a load high and lower the load as soon as possible.

Comment: Also if the road is not perfectly flat but at an angle, the higher the COM is, the easier it is to no longer be over the base of support.

Comment: @enumaris As I understand it, the CoM only moves upwards, which means the base of the forklift doesn't move horizontally. Hence, it shouldn't have any effect on its balance, right ("balance" meaning it won't tend to tip over)? I'm talking only about the situation where the forklift isn't moving and stands on flat floor.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký In the case that the object is lifted directly vertically, the COM will move up directly vertically. This will not effect whether the COM is over the base if the forklift isn't moving and stands on perfectly flat ground. However, the higher the COM is, the easier it is to get it to tip over by e.g. applying a force to the top of the forklift, or tilting the forklift slightly. That's the definition of "balance" that I was using. Easiness to tip over not whether it will actually tip over or not.